# How to find out the reason and solution to this problem of import python modules in Vim

Tags: python, vim

I am trying to set up python in Vim, but I failed to get it to work. It always throws an exception named `UnicodeDecodeError`.

I have installed gvim on windows 10. And also installed python 3 with the corresponding version.
Vim can find the python37.dll and the command

```
:echo has('python3')
```

returns 1 as expected.

My vim with python works only when no modules except for the builtin ones are imported.

For example:

```
:py3 print('a')
```

works pretty well.

```
:py3 import vim
```

or

```
:py3 import sys
```

are also working.

However, if I write a simple python script vim_test.py like this

```py
print('This is for vim test')
```

then try to import it in vim as

```
:py3 import vim_test
```

it will give an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 963, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 906, in _find_spec
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1280, in find_spec
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1252, in _get_spec
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 9: invalid start byte
```

It cannot import any python module in Vim.

But it can run this script directly by

```
:py3file vim_test.py
```

if the script file vim_test.py is in the current directory.

What could be the reason for this problem? 
And how can I solve it?
I expected to be able to use vim plugins written in python.
With this problem, I cannot achieve that.

Comment: The Windows shell sets the encoding to CP1258 (or some other non-utf-8 encoding) by default, which could be the source of your problem. I'm not sure how to fix this with Python within vim within Windows, but I'd search in the direction of changing the encoding Vim is working in, if you can.